# Import .db file into MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new in using MySQL database and need some help.
The scenario is pretty much like this:
I collect data from some sensor which come with their own software. The software builds a .db file as it takes data from the sensors and saves it locally in the computer.

My problem is to collect this data from the .db file and input it into a MySQL database with a certain frequency.

Is it possible to create a script that updates the MySQL database with .db files (lets say every 5 secs)?
Can you provide some direction on what to use?

link for the db file:
http://www.filedropper.com/file_45

Comment: what is the format of the .db file? IS it like CSV?

Comment: I believe it is in the same format as CSV

Comment: Please include some of the `.db` file so that the format may be inspected

Comment: it will be something like this in the link
http://www.monnit.com/images/sensor-data/Vehicle-Profile-1-Data.jpg

Comment: I dont have an actual .db file. I asked for it and once i have it I will post it here. But i am pretty sure should be something like the one i posted above. thnx

Comment: just posted the db file I need help with

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: yes... see my answer below. You can use sqlite with php or mostly any other programming language. You might not even need to use mysql.

Comment: also... you might want to add my name in your "comment answers" so that I get notified ;)... something like @Manatax any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

you can use cron for Linux or Scheduler for Windows.

**EDIT:**

For the File you uploaded, you need to install SQLite.
Check [**this**](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) for the command line access to the data.

You might want to check [**this**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) out if you want to make a web interface for your system.

Comment: I have never used cron before. I am using myPhp admin to create database. Do you see any way cron can come into help? Can it be set up into a frequency. Also, the program that comes with sensors doesnt support linux

Comment: Read the link from "cron". What is your environment?

Comment: I am using windows XP (can use 7 as well). Linux is not an option because the program that collects the sensor data does not run on Linux.

Comment: then you can use the windows scheduler with a .bat script... I would use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) in your position... or c++ if it was for a customer that should not see the code that inserts into the db (that has the password and all)

Comment: @a_el Was the answer useful?